# Dirac's theroem for bipartite graphs

Tags: graph-theory, bipartite-graphs, matching-theory, hamiltonicity

The theorem of Dirac that any graph $G$ on $n\geq 3$ vertices with minimum degree $\delta(G)≥n/2$ contains a Hamilton cycle is one of the classical results of graph theory.

Is there are analogous version which correlates the minimum degree of the vertices in a bipartite graph to guarantee a Hamiltonian cycle ( or alternatively a perfect matching)?

Answer (score 3):

Yes, there is.

We have the following theorem of Bondy (1969):

> Let $G = (X,Y,E)$ be a simple bipartite graph with $|X|=|Y|=n\ge 2$. Let the vertices of $X$ and $Y$ be indexed with increasing degrees (that is, $X = \{x_1, \dots, x_n\}$ with $\deg(x_1) \le \deg(x_2) \le \dots \le \deg(x_n)$ and $Y = \{y_1, \dots, y_n\}$ with $\deg(y_1) \le \deg(y_2) \le \dots \le \deg(y_n)$). If $$\deg(x_j) \le j, \deg(y_k) \le k \implies \deg(x_j) + \deg(y_k) \ge n+1$$ then $G$ has a Hamiltonian cycle.

This is much more complicated than Dirac's theorem, but as a weaker corollary, we have:

> Let $G = (X,Y,E)$ be a simple bipartite graph with $|X|=|Y|=n\ge 2$. If $\delta(G) \ge \frac{n+1}{2}$, then $G$ has a Hamiltonian cycle.

Just minimum degree $\frac n2$ would not be enough, since then $G$ could be two disjoint copies of $K_{n/2, n/2}$.

I'm getting Bondy's theorem from Chapter 10 of Berge's *Graphs and Hypergraphs*, which is my go-to for Hamiltonian cycle condition theorems.

Comment: Thanks a lot. You the real MVP.

Just one small query.
I have the book you are mentioning.
I have found the Bondy's theorem which you are mentioning on Page 215.
Is the corollary also mentioned in that book?
I need to cite the corollary and I wish to find the exact wording.

Please help.

Comment: The corollary is not there, but it's easy to prove from the theorem; if $\delta(G) \ge \frac{n+1}{2}$, then $\deg(x_j) + \deg(y_k) \ge \delta(G) + \delta(G) = n+1$ no matter which $x_j, y_k$ we pick.